# How to get Rake file parameter in Rspec

Tags: ruby, selenium, rspec, rake

I have done the sample for the concept of executing automation testcase as parallel using Rake and Rspec. But dont know how to get the passed parameter in rake file to rspec file. Anyone please help.

Sample Rake File:-

```
require 'rspec/core/rake_task'
RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:spec)
namespace :spec do
  task :foo, :arg1, :arg2 do |t, args|
      do_something
    end

  desc "Run the unit specs"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:unit, :arg1, :arg2)  do |t, args|
    puts "#{args}"
    t.pattern = "test_spec.rb"
  end

  desc "Run the integration specs"
  RSpec::Core::RakeTask.new(:integration, :arg1, :arg2) do |t, args|
    puts "#{args}"
    t.pattern = "test_spec.rb"
  end 
end

task:int do
  Rake::Task["spec:integration"].invoke(123,456)
end

task:uint do
  Rake::Task["spec:unit"].invoke(8888,1111)
end

multitask :all => ["int", "uint"]
```

Rspec File:-

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
require "rspec"

describe "Test Execution" do

  before(:each) do
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    @base_url = "http://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @driver.manage.window.maximize
  end

  it "Executing testcase steps" do

    @driver.get(@base_url + "/")
    @driver.find_element(:id, "employee_email").send_keys "test1@mail.com"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "password").send_keys "1234"
    @driver.find_element(:id, "login_submit").click
  end

  after(:each) do
    @driver.quit   
  end
end
```

Here i want to get passed parameter in rake file(123,456 & 8888,1111).
Help in Advance!

Comment: How about setting it as a rails env var ?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to specify the arguments this way:

```
namespace :mynamespace do
  desc "my description"
  task :my_task, [:arg1, :arg2] do |task, args|
    do_something_with(args[:arg1], args[:arg2])
  end
end
```